# how can I create a file with file_put_contents that has group write permissions?

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I am using `file_put_contents` to create a file. My php process is running in a group with permissions to write to the directory. When `file_put_contents` is called, however, the resulting file does not have group write permissions (it creates just fine the first time). This means that if I try to overwrite the file it fails because of a lack of permissions.

Is there a way to create the file with group write permissions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You might what to try setting the [`umask`](http://php.net/umask) before calling `file_put_contents` : it will change the default permissions that will be given to the file when it's created.

The other way (better, according to the documentation) is to use [`chmod`](http://php.net/chmod) to change the permissions, just after the file has been created.

*Well, after re-reading the question, I hope I understood it well...*

Comment: for the love of god put a code example in here with your 3 paragraphs

Answer (score 40):

Example 1 (set file-permissions to read-write for owner and group, and read for others):

```
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
chmod($filename, 0664);
```

Example 2 (make file writable by group without changing other permissions):

```
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
chmod($filename, fileperms($filename) | 16);
```

Example 3 (make file writable by everyone without changing other permissions):

```
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
chmod($filename, fileperms($filename) | 128 + 16 + 2);
```

128, 16, 2 are for writable for owner, group and other respectively.

Comment: Be aware that this opens up for a TOCTOU attack. There is a small gap between the file being created and permission is changed. Makes the file readable between

Comment: @JonasLejon There shouldn't be any vulnerabilities here in regards to TOCTOU if the only goal is to add additional permissions though, right? 
If you were trying to secure it and remove permissions in this manner then there could be a split-second vulnerability, if I understand this concern correctly. 
If I'm incorrect and it does expose readability somehow that wasn't already there, then I suppose, if sensitive, you could create the file as empty then change permissions followed by appending data.

Answer (score 2):

To open the file and write over contents then you need write permissions to the file. It's important to understand the distinction. To overwrite the entire file you actually need write permissions to the *directory*.

Use [`chmod()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to set what's appropriate on the file and/or directory if you want to be explicit about it.

Comment: Hmm... I DO have permissions to the directory, the problem is that I want to call file_put_contents several times from different scripts on the same file, but the successive times fail.